# "Decouple X from Y" vs "Decouple X with Y" vs "Decouple X and Y"

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference?

And, what should I use to express a bi-directional decoupling? To me, "decouple X from Y" is unidirectional: I take X and remove it from Y, while Y doesn't move. I'd rather express the fact that I make X and Y independent from each other.

Can I say the following:

> A schema decouples frontend and backend.

I know that `A schema decouples frontend from backend.` is a correct sentence but it doesn't express what I want.

Thanks for everything you guys are doing, this community is wonderful — my English improved so much thanks to you.

Comment: If the entities are peers in most senses then one would normally prefer "and", to reinforce the sense of "peerness".  But, if, say, the red one is smaller than the green one, one would tend to say "decouple the red one from the green one".  But it's very much a matter of personal choice, plus whatever is most idiomatic for the specific technical domain.

Answer (score 1):

A database or CS-related stack exchange would likely be your best place to ask this for industry-specific usage, but from a technical writing perspective there are nuanced differences.

"Decouple X from Y" implies X can be freely modified, and changes to Y should be very limited in scope.

"Decouple X and Y" implies that both are open for modification to ensure decoupling.

"Decouple X with Y" is not idiomatic and I have never seen it used.

For your purposes, you may want to say "and" if the scope of changes are rhetoric or unknown.